# How to hide data from RescueTime while incognito?

Tags: google-chrome

I just starting using [RescueTime](http://www.rescuetime.com) to try to keep track of my productivity, but I've run into a bit of a snag. Generally, I keep track of my unproductive time by being in incognito mode in Google Chrome. However, RescueTime doesn't distinguish between incognito mode and just browsing normally.

Is there a way to get RescueTime to treat incognito mode specially, without using RescueTime's whitelist?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the RescueTime extension is not a web application.

Answer (score 3):

Pause rescue time for some privacy while you are browsing.
https://www.rescuetime.com/privacy_checklist

Comment: Welp that's it, I'm deleting my RescueTime account.